# C++がコンパイルできません

Tags: c++, cygwin

mobaxtermでC++の簡単なコードをコンパイルしたところ、このようなエラーがでました。

```
➤ g++ test.cpp -o test
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr.h:148:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h: 関数 ‘int __gthread_mutex_timedlock(__pthread_mutex_t**, const __gthread_time_t*)’ 内:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:768:12: エラー: ‘pthread_mutex_timedlock’ was not declared in this scope
     return __gthrw_(pthread_mutex_timedlock) (__mutex, __abs_timeout);
            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:768:12: 備考: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_mutex_timedlock’
```

原因がわからないので、このエラーの解決策を知っている方がいたら教えてください。
ソースコードは以下の通りです。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"a";
return 0;
}
```

ありがとうございます。
g++ -Q -vの実行結果を以下に記します。

```
 ➤ g++ -Q -v
組み込み spec を使用しています。
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
ターゲット: i686-pc-cygwin
configure 設定: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.i686/src/gcc-7.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.3.0-3.i686/src/gcc-7.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
スレッドモデル: posix
gcc バージョン 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

初心者なものでやり方があってるかはわかりませんが、やってみたところこのようなエラーがでました。（下記参照）

```
➤ g++ --disable-threads test.cpp -o test
cc1plus: エラー: unknown pass threads specified in -fdisable
```

Comment: CygwinのGCCでしょうか？少し調べただけですが、Thread modelによってはgthr-default.hでエラーになる場合があるという情報があります。GCCのデフォルトオプションなどを確認するために、`g++ -Q -v`を実行し、その結果を質問に追記してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。g++ -Q -vの実行結果を追記いたしました。

Comment: 一度 `--disable-threads` (スレッド無効化)をコンパイルオプションに追加して、どうなるか見て貰えませんか？ただ、オプションを付けるとスレッドを使った並列処理ができなくなってしまうため、根本的解決とは行きませんが、コンパイルだけはできるようになるかなと思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。初心者なものでやり方がわからず、調べてやってみたのですが、やり方自体は合っていますでしょうか。

Comment: あ、ごめんなさい。私が勘違いしてました。スレッドモデルはGCC自体のコンパイル時に決定されるので、GCC自体を変えないと後から変えられませんでした。あとは、Cygwin自体のバグかも知れないので、アップデートするぐらいでしょうか。今手元にCygwinがないので、詳しいところはわからないです。

Comment: オプション`-lpthread`を追加してみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

現状MobaXtermの最新版をインストールし直すことでgccのバージョンが変わり，正常にコンパイル・実行することができます．

質問にある該当のエラーがでるMobaXtermにてaptによるgccのアップデートを実行しても，(gcc-7.3.0が)既に最新であるということになっており，アップデートすることができませんでした．